# Two frame layouts inside linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

This is the code I have now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablet_locations_fragment_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablet_locations_fragment_locations_fragment_list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I think it's clear that I want bottom frame layout to be 90dp high and upper to take the rest of the space, but currently, upper frame layout is taking all of the screen height. How can I fix this? I tried to put layout_height="wrap_content" for upper frame layout, but it's not changing anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

layout_weight is your friend

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablet_locations_fragment_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablet_locations_fragment_locations_fragment_list_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: shouldn't be there a weightSum in the LinearLayout tag?

Comment: @AbdallahAlaraby when just filling it is not needed AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="272dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >


                <fragment
                    android:layout_width="89dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
                    android:name="com.androidipdetector.mbiplobe.actionbaractivity.Frag.Pressure"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"/>

                <fragment
                    android:layout_width="89dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                    android:name="com.androidipdetector.mbiplobe.actionbaractivity.Frag.SunsetFragment"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"/>

                <fragment
                    android:layout_width="89dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
                    android:name="com.androidipdetector.mbiplobe.actionbaractivity.Frag.SunsetFragment"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"/>

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what the problem was and how your answer solves it? :)